# /dev/root not found at the time of booting Cent OS 5.7

Tags: linux, filesystems

Initially I got the error /dev/root not found while booting Cent OS 5.7. I knew the issue at it was because of wrong entry in /etc/fstab which was  /**dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 / ext3 defaults 1 1** Here VolGroup name is wrong it should be /VolGroup01. This is due to I had executed vgrename command. So to solve the issue, I booted the system in rescue mode, and mounted the Cent OS filesystem and rectified the the entry to **/dev/VolGroup01/LogVol00 / ext3 defaults 1 1**. I also did similar changes(gave correct root path) in /boot/grub/grub.conf file and rebooted the system but still got the same error. It says '/dev/root' not found and VolGroup00 not found. It also says VolGroup01 found. I think this /dev/root is created by fstab entry which I mentioned. If yes, then why it is not able to find /dev/root. And if this /dev/root is different and created by something else, then how to create it?

In rescue mode, I could not fing /dev/root path in the mounted filesystem. My assumption is that, /dev/root/ 'Block' is created at the time of boot.

For more information this cent OS installation is with xen, and at the time of booting xen kernel loads successfully.
can anyone help me?

Comment: have you changed something in the udev rules ? or is it a custom kernel ?

Comment: No I didn't change anything in udev rules. And it is not a custom kernel. It's normal Cent OS installation with Virtualization selected, so it installs Xen. It used to run pretty smooth with 50 VMs on it, but due to power shutdown there is hard reboot of the system which led me to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `root=/dev/VolGroup01/LogVol00` as kernel-option in grub. Did you do that?